# Hibernate query order by using alias

Tags: hibernate, sorting, spring-data-jpa, alias

When I want to create query with sorting via JpaRepository or CriteriaQuery, I get hibernate translated query like this:

```
select
        table0_.sys_crt_dttm as sys_crt_4_44_
    from
        `table` table0_ 
    where
        table0_.sys_state=? 
    order by
        table0_.sys_crt_dttm asc
```

This is work for Postgres, but doesn't work for YDB, because it need alias name for column in sorting clause. So I need one of following statements:

```
select
        table0_.sys_crt_dttm as sys_crt_4_44_
    from
        `table` table0_ 
    where
        table0_.sys_state=? 
    order by
        sys_crt_4_44_ asc
```

or

```
select
        table0_.sys_crt_dttm
    from
        `table` table0_ 
    where
        table0_.sys_state=? 
    order by
        table0_.sys_crt_dttm asc
```

Is there a way to set up hibernate to use aliasing in `order by` or to forbid to use aliasing for columns?

I tried to remove aliases from SQL in SqlInterceptor using `sql.replace("(as\\s)([\\w_\\d]+)".toRegex(), "")`, but it breaks my queries in some cases, I guess that hibernate uses aliases somewhere

Comment: as for me, that looks like a bug in YDB, however they do not claim their syntax conforms SQL standards. Have you tried to use position instead of column name in order by clause, i.e.: `order by 1 asc`?

Comment: Unfortunately, order by position doesn't work in YDB too